# Uncheck Checked Boxes checked through Echo from POST[]

Tags: javascript, php, checkbox, http-post, reset

I want to uncheck these boxes on pressing my clear button. Form.reset doesn't work. Not does `getelementbyid.checked = false`.

Here is how I have checked them

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="free" <?php echo empty($_POST['free']) ? '' : '         checked="checked" '; ?>>Free Shipping<br>
```

This is the clear button:

```
<input type="reset" value="clear" onclick="clearform()" style="float:right;        width:80px; margin-right:5px;">
```

This is the function:

```
function clearform()
{
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
   document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = "hidden";
   document.getElementById("searchform").reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add `id` to checkbox. change

```
 <input type="checkbox"  name="free" ...
```

to
    `<input type="checkbox"  name="free" id="free" ...`

add `document.getElementById("free").checked = false;` in `function clearform()`

```
function clearform()
{
    document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("results").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("searchform").reset();
    document.getElementById("free").checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getElementById(), you first need to give an id to your checkbox, just like :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="exempleId" ..... />
```

Then in your javascript, to uncheck the box :

```
document.getElementById("exempleId").checked = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this in other ways like

write this on in this sequence.

```
$check = '';
$check = (isset($_POST['free']) && !empty($_POST['free'])) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';

if(isset($_REQUEST['reset']))
{
    $check = '';
}
```

And change your inputs to

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="free" <?php echo $check; ?>>Free Shipping<br>
```

And Reset button to

```
<input type="reset" value="clear" onclick="clearform()" style="float:right; width:80px; margin-right:5px;" name="reset" >
```